# Can I put "who" after "house"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Sentence: Barney Rubble & his family vacant from his friend Fred's
>   house, **who** got help from Barney to top the aptitude test.

Meaning: Barney Rubble & his family vacant from his friend Fred's
house. Fred got help from Barney to top the aptitude test.

Can I put "who" after "house"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are in a live conversation and very sure the listener is following closely, you should not do this, because it looks like the *who* points to *house*.

> Barney Rubble & his family [were] vacant from his friend Fred's house, who got help from Barney to top the aptitude test.

Do this instead.

> Barney Rubble & his family - who got help from Barney to top the aptitude test - were vacant from his friend Fred's house.

Comment: I think that the OP's sentence is quite unnatural. The way you rephrased it, it became clearer.

Comment: A third option: use the original sentence, but change "who" to "Fred" (and use a period instead of a comma). Repeating something instead of using a pronoun is a very reliable strategy for clarity.